# The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'server_hostname' Ansible

Tags: ansible

Structure:

```json
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "junction_detail_ret_obj": {
            "changed": false, 
            "msg": "All items completed", 
            "results": [
                {
                    "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
                    "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                    "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                    "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                    "ansible_facts": {
                        "activations": [
                            "wga"
                        ], 
                        "product_name": "xxx", 
                        "version": "9.0.7.1"
                    }, 
                    "changed": false, 
                    "cmd": "xxxx")", 
                    "data": {
                        "active_worker_threads": "0", 
                        "authz_rules": "no", 
                        "basic_auth_mode": "filter", 
                        "servers": [
                            {
                                "case_sensitive_url": "no", 
                                "current_requests": "0", 
                                "http_port": "1234", 
                                "local_ip": "", 
                                "operation_state": "Online", 
                                "query_content_url": "/cgi-bin/query_contents", 
                                "query_contents": "unknown", 
                                "server_dn": "", 
                                "server_hostname": "123.22.2.2", 
                                "server_port": "1234, 
                                "server_state": "running", 
                                "server_uuid": "59e78480-5241-11e8-a130-005056a4404b", 
                                "total_requests": "582890", 
                                "virtual_junction_hostname": "123.22.2.2:1234", 
                                "windows_style_url": "no"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "case_sensitive_url": "no", 
                                "current_requests": "0", 
                                "http_port": "1345", 
                                "local_ip": "", 
                                "operation_state": "Online", 
                                "query_content_url": "/cgi-bin/query_contents", 
                                "query_contents": "unknown", 
                                "server_dn": "", 
                                "server_hostname": "1.3.4.5", 
                                "server_port": "9789", 
                                "server_state": "running", 
                                "server_uuid": "5a51fb58-5241-11e8-a130-005056a4404b", 
                                "total_requests": "579245", 
                                "virtual_junction_hostname": "1.3.4.5:9789", 
                                "windows_style_url": "no"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "session_cookie_backend_portal": "no", 
                        "stateful_junction": "no", 
                        "tfim_sso": "no", 
                        "transparent_path_junction": "no"
                    }
                }
                    ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Ansible task:

```yaml
- debug: msg="item output:"{{item.data.servers['server_hostname']}}""
  with_items:
    - "{{ junction_detail_ret_obj['results'] }}"
```

I"m trying to access `server_hostname`, but, I am getting below error. I would like to print `server_hostname` and `server_port`.

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'server_hostname'

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that error is that, `servers` (denoted by `"servers": [ ... ]`) is a list, and has multiple items with `server_hostname` in it. We can get the value of `server_hostname` from this without loop/`with_items`. For this we can use the `json_query` filter.

Example:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ junction_detail_ret_obj | json_query('results[].data.servers[].server_hostname') }}"
```

Note that the JSON sample posted in question was showing invalid. I tweaked a couple of lines to make it valid. Then I could get the expected output:

```
    "msg": [
        "123.22.2.2",
        "1.3.4.5"
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you!! that worked,   I need to pass "server_hostname" and "server_hostname:server_port" ex: 123.22.2.2 and 123.22.2.2:9789 to an openssl command  "openssl s_client -servername {{server_hostname}} -connect {{server_hostname:server_port}} 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -C -noout -dates | grep -i notAfter